# How to set only read operation in fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am making a project in which I have 3 organisation. I want third organisation(Org3) only to have read capabilities but can writing anything to the ledger. I have tried by using ACL i.e "peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/" , but this can wont allow for reading the ledger which I dont want. 
How do i implement this scenario. Please help me, since I am a beginner at hyperledger Fabric. 
I am using hyperledger fabric 1.4.2.
Thank you in Advance.

```
Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051
    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP
        ID: Org2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 8051
    - &Org3
        Name: Org3MSP
        ID: Org3MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Admins:obtains 
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org3.example.com
              Port: 9051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
        V1_3: false
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    ACLs: &ACLsDefault
        peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/MyPolicy
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        MyPolicy:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.client')"   

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
    ThreeOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```